Question about definition of convergent sequence to boundary

If $(z_n) \subset \mathbb{H}$ we wil say that $z_n \to \partial \mathbb{H}$ if, for every compact $K \subset \mathbb{H}$ there exists $N$ so that $z_n \in \mathbb{H} \setminus K$ for all $n > N$.

Note: $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the upper half-plane.
And I need to show that if $\phi : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}$ is the Cayley transform, then $z_n \to \partial \mathbb{H} \iff |\phi(z_n)| \to 1$.
What this definition is about? Has anything to do with convergence definition with neighborhoods? Thanks!

What have you tried up to now? Put that in your post.

@YourLordJoyBoy I don't tried anything. Is just a definition. But I don't understand what it want to say and why precisely $K$ needs to be compact

Where did this definition come from? It describes topology of 1-point compactification

@MoisheKohan the book is called "Complex made Simple" by David C. Ullrich (page 327). I was thinking that is from 1-point compactification because there all open sets are open sets from initial space + ${\infty} \cup$ complements of closed and compact sets. But still don't understand how it works

Can you give me a book or something to read more about convergence in 1-point compactification space?

I'd suggest adding where this definition came from in your post.

The definition above ($z_n \to \partial \mathbb{H}$) just means that any limit point of $z_n$ (thought as a complex sequence) is on the boundary of the upper plane so is real or is infinity.
To prove your result you just need to show that if $z_n \to r \in \mathbb R$ then $|\phi(z_n)| \to 1$ which is obvious since $|\phi(r)|=1$ (and $\phi(r)$ exists and is finite) and also that if $z_n \to \infty$ then $|\phi(z_n)| \to 1$ which again is obvious since $\phi(\infty)=1$; this proves one implication, while the reverse follows by contradiction since if $|\phi(z_n)| \to 1$ and $z_n$ has a limit point $w$ in the upper plane itself, then for the corresponding sequence $z_{n_k} \to w$ we have $\phi(z_{n_k}) \to \phi(w)$ and $|\phi(w)|<1$ contradicting the hypothesis.
Note that this result proves that the one-point compactification of the upper plane is a closed disc where you join the real line at one infinity point to make a circle which of course is intuitively obvious, but the Cayley transform gives an explicit homeomorphism.

Thanks, Conrad! I understand now! Great as as always!

happy to be of help

The sequence $(-1)^n+\frac{i}{n}$ satisfies your definition, but does not converge in a neighborhood sense, unless you consider the one-point compactification of the upper half-plane. This is similar to convergence in the one-point compactification of the complex plane, also known as the Riemann sphere.

Conrad explained this.
